# Suppress warning messages in Thor CLI app

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, stdout, thor

I've built a Thor CLI app that uses a number of external gems. When I run it I get warning messages from those gems cluttering my output- how can I suppress this?

**Clarification:** I want to suppress the *warning* messages only, but still receive the standard output for my app, including errors and `puts` results.

For example, when I use these same gems in my Sinatra app, I don't get all the warning messages emanating from the gem code like I do with Thor.

**EXAMPLE** (Derived from http://willschenk.com/making-a-command-line-utility-with-gems-and-thor/)

```
require 'thor'
require 'safe_yaml'

module Socialinvestigator
  class HammerOfTheGods < Thor
    desc "hello NAME", "This will greet you"
    long_desc <<-HELLO_WORLD

    `hello NAME` will print out a message to the person of your choosing.

    HELLO_WORLD
    option :upcase
    def hello( name )
      greeting = "Hello, #{name}"
      greeting.upcase! if options[:upcase]
      puts greeting
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, because we're requiring the `safe_yaml` gem, every time we run a command we'll get the following warnings in our output:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4/lib/safe_yaml.rb:28:
>   warning: method redefined; discarding old safe_load
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:290: warning:
>   previous definition of safe_load was here
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4/lib/safe_yaml.rb:52:
>   warning: method redefined; discarding old load_file
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:470: warning:
>   previous definition of load_file was here

We're using a number of different gems and getting a whole array of warnings that are cluttering our output...

Comment: It would be nice to have a code example to play about with?

Comment: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) solution: Fix the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could potentially submit a Pull request and suppress the message in the dependency or raise an issue asking the gem developers to sort it out for you

Otherwise, this is something I have used before - It's probably from somewhere on SO (or the internet in general) but I can't remember where...

So you basically wrap the noisy method from the dependency with a `silence` method which simply pushes the STDOUT to a StringIO object and then back again to STDOUT...

```
require 'stringio'
def silence
  $stdout = temp_out = StringIO.new 
  yield
  temp_out.string
ensure
  $stdout = STDOUT
end

out = silence { run_dependency_method }
puts out # if in dev mode etc...
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496019/suppresing-output-to-console-with-ruby

Comment: my bad I wasn't clear. I still need the standard output, I just don't want the warning messages coming out of the gems. See my edits above...

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a global variable to define the verboseness of the output. `nil` means no warnings, `false` is the *"normal"* mode and `true` is extra verbose (adds some additional runtime information, equivalent to running `ruby --verbose`):

```
def without_warnings
  verboseness_level = $VERBOSE
  $VERBOSE = nil

  yield
ensure
  $VERBOSE = verboseness_level
end

# Doesn't show warnings about overwriting the constant
without_warnings do
  Foo = 42
  Foo = 'bar'
end

# Still shows normal output
without_warnings { puts 42 }

# Still shows and throws errors
without_warnings { raise 'wtf' }
```

---

If you have control over how the program is ran, you can instead use ruby's `-W` flag with respective values `0`, `1` or `2` (in this case `ruby -W 0`).

Answer (score 0):

@Yarin,

Following up on @Ismail's answer, you could extend this solution by overloading the new "temporary" StringIO inside the `silence` method to filter out messages that contain the word "warning".

Here's an example:

```
require 'stringio'

class FooIO < StringIO
        def puts s
                super unless s.start_with? "WARN"
        end
end

def silence
  $stdout = temp_out = FooIO.new
  yield
  temp_out.string
ensure
  $stdout = STDOUT
end

def foo
        puts "INFO : Hello World!"
        puts "WARN : Oops.. This is a warning..."
        puts "ALRT : EVERYONE IS GOING TO DIE!!!"
end

out = silence { foo }

puts out
```